# Can't apply 'Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/read' permission to my azure application

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-active-directory

I followed these exact directions:

https://cloudrain.in/clients/index.php/knowledgebase/4626/Why-is-Application-permissions-disabled-in-Azure-ADandsharp039s-Request-API-permissions.html

But when I go to add a permission:

[image]

I see this

[image]

I don't understand why it's so hard to apply a read permission to a service account on azure. Does azure just not care?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved following this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-create-service-principal-portal

It's a really long article, but basically you need to apply a role at the resource group or subscription level to the AD application. Or, that's how I got it working at least. It's wildly un-intuitive.